# Handle same navigation drawer but change header text on every activity

Tags: android

Is there a way we can have same navigation drawer on each activity but with change in the header text? For instance I got two activities, my home activity will display a header text as home and my "about us" activity will display "about us" header text but all will have the same navigation settings.

BaseActivity

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
 public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;

public DrawerLayout drawer;
ImageView navDrawerBtn;

HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
List<String> listDataHeader;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

protected LinearLayout fullLayout;
protected FrameLayout actContent;

@Override
public void setContentView(final int layoutResID) {
    fullLayout= (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.home, null); // Your base layout here
    actContent= (FrameLayout) fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, actContent, true); // Setting the content of layout your provided to the act_content frame
    super.setContentView(fullLayout);
    // here you can get your drawer buttons and define how they should behave and what must they do, so you won't be needing to repeat it in every activity class

    prepareListData();

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }


    navDrawerBtn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.headerDrawer);
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        expListView.setIndicatorBounds(402,465);    
    } else {        
        expListView.setIndicatorBoundsRelative(402,465);    
    } 

    drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);


    navDrawerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!drawer.isDrawerOpen(expListView)) {
                drawer.openDrawer(expListView);
                } else {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(expListView);
                }

            }
        });


    //listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // Listview Group click listener
    expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, long id) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    // Listview Group expanded listener
    expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // Listview Group collasped listener
    expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    // Listview on child click listener
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            switch (childPosition) {
            case 0: 
                Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(a);
                break;

            case 1: 
                Intent b = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScheduleActivity.class);
                startActivity(b);
                break;
}
            return false;
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
 }


/*
 * Preparing the list data
 */
protected void prepareListData() {


    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("VRP Medical Bay");
    //listDataHeader.add("");
    //listDataHeader.add("");

    // Adding child data

    List<String> listUnderVRP = new ArrayList<String>();

    listUnderVRP.add("eDataClinical");
    listUnderVRP.add("Schedule");
    listUnderVRP.add("Dictate");
    listUnderVRP.add("View Messages");
    listUnderVRP.add("Reports for Signature");
    listUnderVRP.add("View Billing");
    listUnderVRP.add("View State");


    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), listUnderVRP); // Header, Child data
    //listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
    //listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);


}



}
```

my home layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="73dp"
android:background="@color/actionbar" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/headerDrawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/actionHeaderText"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/headerDrawer"
    android:src="@drawable/e_icon"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"  />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/actionHeaderText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="@string/actionbar_title"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="monospace" />
```

```
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

     <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_width="470dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_selector"
         android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:childDivider="#4abcd7"
       android:divider="#626262"
         android:dividerHeight="4dp"

        android:cacheColorHint="#fff" >
    </ExpandableListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My Billing Activity:

```
public class ViewBillingActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_billing_test);


}
```

my billing layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="73dp"
    android:background="@color/actionbar" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/headerDrawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/actionHeaderText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/headerDrawer"
        android:src="@drawable/e_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionHeaderText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="@string/view_billing"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="monospace" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="@color/view_billing_bg"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/latestBillingTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/latest_billing"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/latestBillingDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/latestBillingTitle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="(03/01/2014 - 03/31/2014)"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="720dp"
    android:layout_height="820dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingBottom="50dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout7"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/view_mssgs_id_bg" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vbTxtID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="024"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayout7"
            android:background="@color/tile_box" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="@string/vb_outstanding_balance"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vbTxTOutBalance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
                android:text="0.00"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@color/tile_box" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vbTxtLastMonthBill"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="2004.50"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/vbTxtLastMonthBill"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/vbTxtLastMonthBill"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:text="@string/vb_last_month_bill"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

     <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="45dp"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout3"
         android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
         android:background="@color/tile_box" >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/vbTxtPaymentReceived"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
             android:text="2004.50"
             android:textColor="@color/white"
             android:textSize="24sp" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/vbTxtPaymentReceived"
             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/vbTxtPaymentReceived"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
             android:text="@string/vb_payments_received"
             android:textColor="@color/white"
             android:textSize="24sp"
             android:textStyle="bold" />
     </RelativeLayout>

      <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/relativeLayout5"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="45dp"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout4"
         android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
         android:background="@color/tile_box" >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/vbTxtPaymentReceivedDate"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
             android:text="04/05/2014"
             android:textColor="@color/white"
             android:textSize="24sp" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/vbTxtPaymentReceivedDate"
             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/vbTxtPaymentReceivedDate"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
             android:text="@string/vb_payment_received_date"
             android:textColor="@color/white"
             android:textSize="24sp"
             android:textStyle="bold" />
     </RelativeLayout>

      <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/relativeLayout6"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="45dp"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout5"
         android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
         android:background="@color/tile_box" >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/vbTxtBalance"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
             android:text="1575.75"
             android:textColor="@color/white"
             android:textSize="24sp" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/vbTxtBalance"
             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/vbTxtBalance"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
             android:text="@string/vb_balance"
             android:textColor="@color/white"
             android:textSize="24sp"
             android:textStyle="bold" />
     </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, according to [design guidelines](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html), it is better to set header text within the ActionBar when navigation drawer is open rather than having separate `TextView` header within navigation drawer layout.

But in case you really-really need separate "header" text within your navigation drawer - layout (and the way you interact with it) for your navigation drawer is exactly the same as any other regular layout you usually have in your activities. Just declare `TextView`, give it some reasonable id, get this text view in your activity (`findViewById()`) and set proper text

Comment: Emmm, you can make it work, but I wouldn't do that just because you usually have base activity to implement some common business logic, but definitely not to share UI... Well, if you are 100% sure what you are doing - then yes, you can handle that by having a base activity

Comment: i added my code, but it seems when i click the navigation icon, it doesnt show the supposed detail on the expandable list, and wasnt able to change the header text

Comment: when i click the navigation icon it dims the application, it only show that it is working but the problem is it doesnt show the datas on the expandable list

Comment: it looks like a different problem to me and should be asked as a separate question. After a quick look I can see you are trying to set `null` adapter to your list. Why do you expect it to work?

Comment: yes i just notice it just now, sorry for that, its working well,my only problem now is how to change the header text

Answer (score 0):

Write Change Text Code in `onDrawerClosed` and `onDrawerOpened` methods according to the text you want to display..

Comment: hi @Mitesh kind of interesting, how do you do that?like for example i got 3 activities, 1 activity will shoe header text "one", for 2, header text "two", and so on, pls help me.

Comment: If you are using `Drawer` then try using `fragments` instead of `Activity` means the class which you are gonna call should extends `Fragments`

Comment: sorry mitesh im new to android, trying to cope on things, do you have a sample code?i think the first comment is near to answer, maybe i can  set a if else statement on the baseactivity for each header text view on every activity,but still i dnt know how to do it..sorry

Comment: Please check this example.. [Android Drawer](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

Comment: Download the code from the link I have given above.. and run that code.. you will get answer to your question.

Comment: Hi Mitesh its really hard to implement the code fro ,y app using baseactivity, is there a way i can use any, such as  case 5: 
               
                  Intent f = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewBillingActivity.class);
                  startActivity(f);
                  headerText.setText("View Billing");
                  break;

Comment: Have you tried the code?? from the link I have given??

Comment: yes but it uses fragment, i wanted to use base activity since thats the one im using, i was able to fix the problem by setting a default header text on each activity, anyway thank you for your help Mitesh